# Opening files of names

Tags: python, file

When I try to open the file for this function, I don't get all the names. I want to get this:

```
Smith, Joe,9911991199,smithjoe9,99,88,77,66
Ash, Wood,9912334456,ashwood,11,22,33,44
Full, Kare,9913243567,fullkare,78,58,68,88
```

But I get this when I test the function:

```
['Ash, Wood,9912334456,ashwood,11,22,33,44\n', 'Full, Kare,9913243567,fullkare,78,58,68,88\n']
```

Can anyone please help me fix this? How can I include the first person's name as well?

```
def open_grades_file(filename):
    '''(str) -> file

    Open filename, read past its one-line header and
    return the open file.
    '''
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    file.readline()
    for line in file:
        line.rstrip('\n')
        return file
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are returning file. Even more what are you gaining from stripping the '\n' if you are not saving the result.

Comment: You return from the first line iteration...

Comment: I was hoping that it would skip over the header

Comment: I don't get how you get any output at all from that function. Surely you havn't shown us the code line that reads in the displayed data, nor the line that prints it.

Comment: So return the file after the readline?

Comment: I get a list when I test it

Comment: What is the reason for the return? As its probably not needed here.

Comment: The returned values in the question is not the actual return of the code. You probably read the lines later, from the returned file object. The first line disappears because of the `file.readline()` statement but that seems intentional given the docstring. The second line disappears because of `for line in file:`, this advances the file position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all file after the one-line header:

```
def open_grades_file(filename):
    '''(str) -> (file)

    Open filename, read past its one-line header and
    return file.
    '''
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    file.readline()

    return file

# read all file past its one-line header
f = open_grades_file(filename).read()

print(f)
```

will print:

```
Smith, Joe,9911991199,smithjoe9,99,88,77,66
Ash, Wood,9912334456,ashwood,11,22,33,44
Full, Kare,9913243567,fullkare,78,58,68,88
```

Comment: How do I test this now? f = open_grades_file(filename)
f.readline()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 4, line 1
builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'. I get that when I test it

Comment: Please post your full code in question not here in comment. Edit your question.

Comment: I figured it out, but where do I add the rstrip() to remove the '\n'?

Comment: You do not need rstrip() if you want to print it exactly as in question.

Comment: Ok but how would we get rid of the '\n' if we wanted to?

Comment: Add this line: `f = ''.join(f.split('\n'))` after `f = open_grades_file(filename).read()`

Comment: @bigd Future readers may find this question interesting. Does any answer give you a solution? Accepting any answer that helped you may help future readers too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the function to actually correspond to its docstring, use:

```
def open_grades_file(filename):
    '''(str) -> file

    Open filename, read past its one-line header and
    return the open file.
    '''
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    file.readline()
    return file
```

But it's a very strange thing to do, a function like this would be more pythonic:

```
def read_grade_lines(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            yield line.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you need to return anything if you are just trying to get something printed to the console or need to update some variable but this simple function will print all the lines to the console in order.

```
def open_grades_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

If you can provide more context to what it is you are trying to do I can form a better answer.

If you want to print out all lines except for the first one you could have a true/false variable that will allow you to skip the first line.

Something like this:

```
x = False

def open_grades_file(filename):
    global x
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if x == True:
                print(line.rstrip('\n'))
                return line.rstrip('\n') # this return line should work for you. Though I am not sure what its for in your case.
            else:
                x = True # sets x to true after the first line is read.
    x = False # resets for next use of the function

open_grades_file("data")
```

Comment: I want to read past the one line header and how can I do it using return?

Comment: @bigd I have updated my answer with something that may work for you

Comment: How can I do it using return?

Comment: @bigd what do you mean how? Just add return to the line that is printing the data. I have added a return line to the code. Please explain what it is you are trying to accomplish with the return line so I can provide a clear answer.